# Linux Kernel NUMA related variable in struct task_struct

Tags: linux, fork, numa

Previously, Thank you for watching and answering about my question.

I'm watching the code of linux kernel specifically, linux/kernel/kthread.c

In the file, there's a function tsk_fork_get_node as below

```
/* called from do_fork() to get node information for about to be created task */
int tsk_fork_get_node(struct task_struct *tsk)
{
#ifdef CONFIG_NUMA
    if (tsk == kthreadd_task)
        return tsk->pref_node_fork;
#endif
    return NUMA_NO_NODE;
}
```

I can't find the exact meaning of pref_node_fork variable. and i want to know the full name of it.

I also found the patch (commit id 207205a2ba, with "git show 207205a2ba")

But there's no explain for the pref_node_fork variable in task_struct.

Summary :

1. I want to know the exact meaning of pref_node_fork variable.
2. I want to know the full name of pref_node_fork variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow what's the problem here. The commit message clearly states it extends the API so that when spawning a new kernel thread you can tell what numa domain should be used. And then one can see it is done by smuggling the node parameter through the perf_node_fork field and using it on fork in tsk_fork_get_node.

I have to ask why are you looking at this code.

Comment: I don't need any fix things. I'm just questioning the meaning of tsk_fork_get_node variable. And I'm just reading the linux kernel source code line by line. and the author of the path only explained clearly other thing except the 'tsk_fork_get_node'

Comment: Reading line by line is wrong. Instead, you should learn about general idioms used thorough the kernel and to that end you should stick to a simple subsystem.

Comment: I'm studying with other guyz. not alone. we are watching the codes line by line and have a communication each other for the meaning of the line.
I understand what you are saying, but it is also good for understanding the whole of the meaning of kernel. I mean overall concept not the routine of subsystem